# Como aplicar control de cambios a archivos excel ya creados?

Tags: excel, microsoft-office, office365

Me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de aplicar el control de cambios para todos los archivos excel que ya tengo creados, sin necesidad de tener que entrar a cada uno de ellos.

Comment: Que has intentado?, pon un ejemplo mínimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, aquí las preguntas que no muestran algún intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el [Recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Que yo sepa no, la única manera de tener un cierto control sobre un archivo Excel es bloqueando rangos con seguridad. Y aun así, un control de cambios en una hoja de cálculo sería bastante duro porque cada vez que haces algo en una hoja, Excel en segundo plano recalcula TODA la hoja, y todo eso quedaría registrado como cambios. Sería una locura. Si lo que quieres es saber si alguien cambió el valor de una celda, que yo sepa no se puede. Si lo que quieres evitar es que la gente cambie cosas, empieza protegiendo los archivos con contraseña o poniéndolos como solo lectura.